# Testing OnSubscriptionData functionallity in @apollo/client

Tags: jestjs, graphql, enzyme, apollo-client

I'm currently using the @apollo/client graphql npm package for react, and I have subscriptions that I'd like to test their functionallity in the onSubscriptionData function, but can't seem to find anywhere examples to that. pls help me :)